# Trying to run a relay, not working

Tags: relays

I am trying to run a tor relay node (non exit), but when i copy the lines into the torrc file shown on the tor website, and try to launch tor browser, i get this message:[image: error message]

Also on a side note, how do i ensure that I am running a non exit relay?

Comment: Can you clarify which lines you've copied and how you edited the torrc file?

Comment: Infact, if you could just include your `torrc` that'd probably be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without actually seeing what your `torrc` file says the only information I can give you is that you don't actually copy and paste the stuff from the tor site to the file cause those lines are placed all along the file, all you have to do is go through and uncomment them.

It also looks like you are editing the file for the browser, if you are going to be hosting a relay I highly recommend paying for a VPS from a service like [DigitalOcean](http://digitalocean.com/) and if you aren't interested in doing that I recommend setting up a virtual machine running Ubuntu of some sort and then installing Tor from the command line with a tutorial like [such](https://unindented.org/articles/run-a-tor-relay-on-ubuntu-trusty/).